# Is there any to install rbenv offline?

Tags: ruby, installation, rbenv

I am trying to install rbenv without the internet. Unlike RVM which has a whole page dedicated to offline installation, I could not find anything similar to that for rbenv.

Is there any way to install it offline? Also a way to add different versions of Ruby to it without going online (like RVM , you add the tar.bz2 of the Ruby version to $rvm_path/archives)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to install it offline?

Installation simply consists of unpacking the `rbenv` distribution into a directory and editing a few files. Neither of the two tasks requires you to go online.

> Also a way to add different versions of Ruby to it without going online (like RVM , you add the tar.bz2 of the Ruby version to $rvm_path/archives)

`rbenv` only manages Rubies that have already been installed, and all it needs to know for that is the directory they are installed in. Again, no need to go online.